# data formatting of Z-buffer

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I am currently trying to generate synthetic depth images using blender. I understand that current the z buffer can be output using the composition nodes into OpenEXR and I have successfully done that. How ever when I open the image in opencv and read the values of each pixel, it does not seems to correctly reflect the distance of the pixel from the camera.

I read  that when Z buffer is exported into OpenEXR, each pixels contains the Z-buffer,alpha value and color render infomaitons. Is this information correct? If so how am I able to extract just the Z-buffer data?.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me this question belongs to a forum for opencv and not here.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the Z pass is a greyscale image that is generated taking into account the clipping points of the camera (start and end). Form the wiki:"The depth map is inverse linear (1/distance) from the camera clip start". It can be read like this: black pixels correspond with the objects at the start clipping point close to camera. White pixels will then be objects far form the camera at the end clip point. So the information is encoded in tones. The scale (and distance information) will vary according to the clip points of your camera.

Comment: Also the Z pass is encoded with values that go way beyond the normal 0-1 black to white values on blender. Hence the need of the OpenEXR format to store the Z pass information properly.

Comment: @cegaton The pixel values actually correspond the distance from the camera in Blender Units. If you want an image that stays inside the 0-1 range, you must use either a *Normalize* or a *Map Range* node.

Comment: The answer depends on how you saved the file from blender. Did you use *MultiLayer EXR*? Was it auto saved (e.g. a one frame animation)? etc.

Comment: @gandalf3 I saved it the file output note in the compositor. The image was generated when I render an Image. The file output node has Openexr,rgb,float(selected) with the z buffer checked. I am not sure if MultiLayer EXR was used, where is that option located? Thanks

Comment: my final aim is to extract the distance value of the camera to each pixel much like how kinect will render its depth image.

Comment: @zen It's listed as another format (so it seems you did not.) I think your file should only have the Z information.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.I found out the reason why the distance value was wrong. I read the binaries as integers when they where stored as floating point.